# What is the correct way in Speedment to access a database schema that's different from the default one?

Tags: mysql, speedment

In my project I'm using Speedment for ORM. Of course I want my code properly tested. So I decided to create an identical copy of my default database schema which I wanted to use for unit testing. In this case the name of the original schema is "project" and the name of the copy is "test_project"

My problem is that I don't know how to properly address the other database schema.
 I know that, upon establishing a connection, I can use the method `withSchema("test_project")` to tell speedment which schema to use. 
This works just fine as long as I don't have any columns identifiers in my query.

So this works:

`List <User> users = userManager.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());`

whereas this doesn't:

```
List <User> users = userManager.stream().filter(User.UID.equal(id)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It's telling me this:  `Unknown column 'project.User.uid' in 'where clause`

I don't really understand what's going on there. (Note: I'm quite new to Speedment).
My question is: How can I access my other schema with all its rows properly addressed to it?

Answer (score 0):

This was [a bug in Speedment](https://github.com/speedment/speedment/issues/597). Changing schema `withSchema("test_project")` is the correct way. This will be fixed in Speedment version  3.0.23.